# Loop through multiple urls with Request (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I currently have a app.get() method that uses request and cheerio to pull html from iTunes reviews.

```
// get all reviews
app.get('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {
  var options = {
    url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/customerReviews',
    qs: {
     'displayable-kind': '11',
     'id': 'XXXXXXXXX',
     'page': i,
     'sort': '4'
    },
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'iTunes/10.3.1 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8) AppleWebKit/533.21.1',
      'X-Apple-Store-Front': '143441-1,12',
      'X-Apple-Tz': '-18000',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-us, en;q=0.50',
    }
  } 

  request(options, function(error, response, html) {
    // load html, parse, do work, etc.
    // res.send(results);
  }     
};
```

I want to iterate through this url call with the 'page' query being a variable like below. I am getting a "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." error when trying it this way. How do you go about changing the headers and doing another url call?

```
app.get('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/customerReviews',
      qs: {
       'displayable-kind': '11',
       'id': 'XXXXXXXXX',
       'page': '1',
       'sort': '4'
      },
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'iTunes/10.3.1 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8) AppleWebKit/533.21.1',
        'X-Apple-Store-Front': '143441-1,12',
        'X-Apple-Tz': '-18000',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-us, en;q=0.50',
      }
    } 

    request(options, function(error, response, html) {
      // load html, parse, do work, etc.
    }
  }     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are trying to send the result page in chunks, which does not work.  You can solve this by collecting all of the `request` results then send whatever data you need to back to the client.

Here is an example of doing this using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var async = require('async');

app.get('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {
  async.times(4, function(i, cb) {
      var options = {
        url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/customerReviews',
        qs: {
         'displayable-kind': '11',
         'id': 'XXXXXXXXX',
         'page': i,
         'sort': '4'
        },
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'iTunes/10.3.1 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8) AppleWebKit/533.21.1',
          'X-Apple-Store-Front': '143441-1,12',
          'X-Apple-Tz': '-18000',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-us, en;q=0.50',
        }
      } 
      request(options, function(error, response, html) {
        // load html, parse, do work, etc.
        // var result = ...;
        cb(null, result);
      });
  }, function(err, results) {
    // completed processing of all items
    // array of `request` results are stored in results
    // send data to client here
  });
});
```